# Flurl deserialization issues when calling .NET Web API

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, deserialization, flurl

Currently creating a Xamarin Mobile App which uses an ASP.NET Web API, however, I'm having issues de-serializing the data on the app side.

I've tried a multitude of ways none of which I can get to work. Flurl GetStringAsync & GetAsync work as they should, however, these too show the same issue when trying to serialize the data afterward with GetJsonAsync and don't give any issues on where the problem might be.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFbwV.png

I've checked the data with insomnia and know the API is outputting the correct data.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgoxP.png

Currently have the code as shown however as noted above this doesn't work.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOAhF.png

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

After searching for hours through youtube videos i fixed the issue by changing the data type to a list, with the 'patientdata' object beneath it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfQdy.png